# What are the odds of the case A hitting the flop when 3 of 4 players at a 9 person table are holding an A?

Tags: texas-hold-em, odds

For example let's say its A4 vs AT vs A8 vs KJ.  What are the odds of that 4th A hitting the flop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know 8 cards preflop, often this is easier to work out the chances of this not happening and invert it. Simple maths for this one.

52 cards in a deck, we know 8 already, so cards that can come on the flop would be 52-8=44 cards remaining in the deck. We have three cards coming on the flop, we don't know when the ace will appear so we can compute this all together. You can work this out by working out the odds of it not hitting the flop and get the inverse (43/44) * (42/43) * (41/42) = 0.9318 or 93.18% of not hitting, inverse would be 1 - 0.9318 = 0.0682 or 6.82%

Above example also fits for working out any odds of an event happening.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help out a math challenged fella!  Appreciate it!

Comment: No worries, and welcome to the community!